# Package not deploying everything in it to server

Tags: 2010, development, web-services

I have a package solution as,

```
<Solution xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" SolutionId="id" SharePointProductVersion="14.0">
  <Assemblies>
    <Assembly Location="myaSSEMBLEY.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" />
  </Assemblies>
  <TemplateFiles>
    <TemplateFile Location="Layouts\myWebServices\ssServices.asmx" />
    <TemplateFile Location="Layouts\myWebServices\ssServices.asmx" />
  </TemplateFiles>
</Solution>
```

but it's deploying dlls to gac but not deploying my web services to layout's folder, what could be wrong ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `<RootFiles>, <RootFile>` tags

For example,

```
<Solution xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" SolutionId="id" SharePointProductVersion="14.0">
  <Assemblies>
    <Assembly Location="myaSSEMBLEY.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" />
  </Assemblies>
  <RootFiles>
    <RootFile Location="Layouts\myWebServices\ssServices.asmx" />
    <RootFile Location="Layouts\myWebServices\ssServices.asmx" />
  </RootFiles>
</Solution>
```

Comment: thanks but i don't want to make manual changes

Comment: Also, location is relative from the 14 hive folder and you need to use url: Location="TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\myWebServices\ssServices.asmx". Maybe it will help.